# Moving a sprite with an angle with Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprite

How could I move a sprite from it's original position in line with an angle value : [image: /Users/jules/Desktop/example.png]

I don't want to move it with a target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
float angle = ...;
float deltaPath = ...;

float deltaX = deltaPath * MathUtils.cos(angle);
float deltaY = deltaPath * MathUtils.sin(angle);

sprite.translate(deltaX, deltaY);
```

Comment: What do you mean by delta path ?

Comment: It's a distance between start and end positions of the sprite.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have the end position of the sprite, I just want it to cross the screen with an angle

Comment: Well, then you need to know velocity, right? If you know velocity, you can find distance for the sprite to walk on each frame. So, somewhere in you `render(float delta)` method, you find a `deltaPath = velocity * delta`. And then calculate `deltaX` and `deltaY`.

Comment: Knowing only the angle is not enough, you need to know how fast to move your sprite, right? You should know either a velocity and time, or a total distance and time, which is basically the same thing. If I didn't understand your question correctly, please provide more info.

Comment: If you want to move it instantly, again you need to know a distance.